# SQL Query to get name that appear twice

Tags: sql

I have the below Table

Table1

```
Emp ID | Emp Name
001    | ABC
002    | DEF
003    | GHI
004    | ABC
005    | XYZ
```

I am trying to get EMP ID and Emp Name where Emp Name is same but Emp ID is different. There is primary key in the table

Here the output will be

```
Emp ID | Emp Name
001    | ABC
004    | ABC
```

Comment: What did you try and the actual issue is? which database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify your DBMS, so this is ANSI SQL:

```
select emp_id, emp_name
from (
  select emp_id, emp_name, 
         count(*) over (partition by emp_name) as name_count
  from employee
) t
where name_count > 1^;
```

Comment: My mistake it is in Oracle

Comment: @suzeet: Oracle does support that syntax (it does not support the syntax in the answer you accepted though) The solution using a window function is usually faster then the approach with a self join

Answer (score 0):

Group by `Emp_Name`, select records having count `Emp_ID` more than one and then select all records from table having such `Emp_Name`:

```
select Emp_ID, Emp_Name
from Table1
where Emp_Name in 
    (
        select Emp_Name
        from Table1
        group by Emp_Name
        having count(Emp_ID) > 1
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below.

```
SELECT T1.* FROM
TABLE1 T1
JOIN
(
SELECT EMP_NAME, COUNT(EMP_ID) FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY EMP_NAME HAVING COUNT(EMP_ID) > 1
) T2 ON T1.EMP_NAME = T2.EMP_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem yesterday :) and i believe below code will give you what you want.

Use `INNER JOIN` to make a self join query, then use `HAVING` clause.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (Emp_ID int, Emp_Name varchar(50))

INSERT INTO [#Table1]
(
    [Emp_ID],
    [Emp_Name]
)
SELECT '001','ABC'
UNION ALL SELECT '002','DEF'
UNION ALL SELECT '003','GHI'
UNION ALL SELECT '004','ABC'
UNION ALL SELECT '005','XYZ'

SELECT [t1].[Emp_ID], [t1].[Emp_Name] FROM [#Table1] t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT [#Table1].[Emp_Name] FROM [#Table1] 
    GROUP BY [#Table1].[Emp_Name]
    HAVING COUNT([#Table1].[Emp_ID]) > 1
) t2
    ON [t1].[Emp_Name] = [t2].[Emp_Name]

DROP TABLE [#Table1]
```

Below is the result:

```
Emp_ID  Emp_Name
1       ABC
4       ABC
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo - Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a69a1/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Another `EXISTS` version, but without any aggregating:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
where exists (select 1 from tablename t2
              where t2.Emp_Name = t1.Emp_Name
                and t2.Emp_ID <> t1.Emp_ID)
```

May speed up things a bit. Otherwise I'd try self join version:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
  join tablename t2 on  t2.Emp_Name = t1.Emp_Name
                    and t2.Emp_ID <> t1.Emp_ID
```

Perhaps, depending on data, you need to do `SELECT DISTINCT`.